# Cannot update macOS or format drive of Macbook Pro 2011

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, bootcamp, upgrade, disk-format

I have a MacBook Pro early 2011, 4 GB RAM, i7-Processor and Samsung SSD 500GB drive. I installed Windows 10 via DVD on a partition and macOS El Capitan on another partition.

[image]
[image]

I want to update my macOS to a higher version, but it doesn't work. The problem is, that I can't select my drive.

[image]

The Volume "Apple" is marked as a start volume. But Apple's macOS installer always returns the error, that it can not find any start volume.

I tried to go to Recovery Mode and install the upgrade to Sierra or High Sierra via USB, but I always get the same error.

After that I tried to format the whole driver in Recovery Mode or via USB-Boot, but Mac cannot format any partition or the whole drive. The error is, that are too many mistakes in partitions and Mac cannot format the volume.

If somebody has experience in such a situation and can help me, 
I'll be very happy.

Comment: If you boot to a full macOS system, install TeamViewer 14 and send the credentials (ID/password) to klanomath(at)googlemail.com I can have a personal look. **Don't post ID/passwords here!** Reading your question it's rather unclear what's wrong with your drive.

Comment: If you have a backup (like a time machine backup), you can repartition the drive from the recovery mode. Even if it does not let you to format the drive, it should let you to partition it. Choose the drive itself and see if partition button is enabled. Note: parititioning kills all data on the disk, so think twice!